# Using Dollar Signs to Escape Apostrophe Characters

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping

I ran this sql query:

```
select *
from table
where customer_name = $$'name's'$$;
```

And I got no results returned.

I ran this sql query:

```
select *
from table
where customer_name = $$name's$$;
```

And I got all of the results back.

I thought double dollar sign characters ignored apostrophe characters?

What am I missing?

Comment: why would you have `%%` there?  that'd be a syntax error, since your $$ string is now unterminated.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. That was a typo.

Comment: `'` means nothing special in a $$ string. that means you're looking for a field with the literal characters `'`, `n`, `a`. etc... in it.

Comment: Ah, so just to make sure I understand this correctly, in my first query, the query is looking for 'name's'  EXACTLY like this and in my second query, it's looking for name's EXACTLY like that?

Comment: your first one wants a value of `'name's'`, WITH the quotes, stored in the database. the second one is lookin for `name's`, WITHOUT the surrounding quotes.

Comment: How did I not catch this? Thank you :)